# How to clear browser cache on page load

Tags: php, html, jquery

```
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0");
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
header("Pragma: no-cache");
```

I tried to use the code above but on some systems it is not working. For example, in my client's browser it does not work. What is a global way to clear the browser cache when the page loads?

Comment: Meta data mostly work in the browser helpfull to clear cache 
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="-1" />

Answer (score 0):

Meta data mostly work in the browser helpfull to clear cache

```
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" /> <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" /> <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="-1" />
```